# .htaccess / ModRewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess

I have been attempting to use .htaccess rewrites for a link shortening service I am writing.

I am attempting to achieve the following:

**URL:** http://domain.com/keyhere : redirects to http://domain.com/link.php?key=keyhere

**URL:** http://domain.com/keyhere+ : redirects to http://domain.com/analytics.php?key=keyhere

I have achieved the first one, but am unable to redirect it with the trailing +

My code for this is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ link.php?key=$1 [L]
```

If anybody could point me in the right direction with the Rewrite rules required, that'd be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group`(.*)` is greedy, so you will need a second rule which matches the `+`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Also added non-existing directory condition
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# What's this for??
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !#

# Match everything up to + ,followed by + first...
RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\+$ analytics.php?key=$1 [L]

# Next rule matches everything when there is no +
RewriteRule ^([^+]*)$ link.php?key=$1 [L]
```

The pattern `[^+]*` means to match zero or more (`*`) characters up to but not including a `+`.  When that is followed by `$` (end of the string), the implication is that the string contains no `+`.

To test for the presence of `+` at the end of the string, we then include `\+$`. The `+` must be escaped because it is a special character in regular expressions but we want its literal presence. Therefore `^([^+]*)\+$` means *capture all characters (except `+`  up to the `+` at the very end of the string*.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you a million times over! Now time for me to try and understand it! :)

Comment: `^([^+]*)\+$` is the regex. `^` means the start of the string, `[^+]` means "any character that isn't a plus" and `*` means "repeated 0 or more times", and lastly `\+` means the character "plus", and it has to be escaped as it's used regularly in regex. Lastly, `$` means "the end of the string".